# form validation email jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, email

```
if ( $("#form").validate().form() == true ) {

    $('#form').submit( function() {
        var mail = $("#mail_content").val();
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "process.php",  
            data: "mail="+ mail,  
            success: function(){  
            $('.email').fadeOut(200);
            $('.notified').delay(200).fadeIn(200);
            }  
        });
        return false;
    });

    }

    else {}
```

i think the

```
 if ( $("#form").validate().form() == true ) {
```

is not what is has to be

my resource:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/form

the submit ajax part is working, i only want to validate the inputted emailadress

merci for your help

EDIT:

i forgot

i have tried this code

```
$("#form").validate({
     submitHandler: function(form) {
       $('#form').submit( function() {

        var mail = $("#mail_content").val();
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "process.php",  
            data: "mail="+ mail,  
            success: function(){  
                $('.email').fadeOut(200);
                $('.notified').delay(200).fadeIn(200);
            }  
        });
        return false;
    });
     }
    });
```

but for some reason i have to click the submit button twice...??

see what i mean here:

http://herenhoek.nl/test/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second code example in your question is almost correct, except for the common mistake of reusing the jQuery object of your form. In this case you do not need to trigger the `submit` event again because you're using an AJAX request to handle the process.

Read the following section of the plugin documentation: [Too much recursion](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator#Too_much_recursion)

The correct syntax would be:

```
$("#form").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var mail = $("#mail_content").val();

        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "process.php",  
            data: "mail="+ mail,  
            success: function() {  
                $('.email').fadeOut(200);
                $('.notified').delay(200).fadeIn(200);
            }  
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: jup that works

i've read that section changed my code but made a mistake

i see my mistake now

thank you for your help

really appreciated